# Function not working when hardcoding instead of using input()

Tags: python, arduino

I'm working with Python on my PC, sending serial commands to an arduino which controls a certain number of stepper motors.
However, in this function:

```py
# takes array of commands to send to motors (in order) and sends commmand arcodinlgy
# each element of commands is an absolute angle (rad) to give to one motor
def send_command(commands):
    if not len(commands) > 0:
        return

    # make command string to send serial
    # (with command separator and line termination)
    command_string = "";
    for i in range(len(commands) - 1):
        command_string += f"{commands[i]:.4f}{COMMAND_SEPARATOR}"
    command_string += f"{commands[-1]:.4f}{LINE_TERMINATOR}"
    # make command string into bytes UTF-8
    # print(command_string)
    command_string = bytes(command_string, "utf-8")

    # send command string serial
    print(f"Sending command: " + str(command_string))
    port.write(command_string)
    # wait for arduino's return_code on serial
    while True:
        if port.inWaiting() > 0:
            return_code = int(port.readline())
            return return_code

# driving code
while True:
    commands = [0, 0]
    commands[0] = float(input("command 1: "))
    commands[1] = float(input("command 2: "))
    return_code = send_command(commands)
    print(f"return code: {return_code}")
```

This code works correctly, but if I don't want user input for the commands :

```py
while True:
    commands = [float(random.random()*pi), float(random.random()*pi)]
    # or even the following doesn't work for exemple:
    # commands = [3.1415, 0.5555]
    return_code = send_command(commands)
    print(f"return code: {return_code}")
    sleep(1)
```

This code doesn't.
I don't get why because in the first case, the line `print(f"Sending command: " + str(command_string))` prints exactly the same as in the second case :

```
Sending command: b'3.1415:0.5555\n'
```

(when input those angles)
But in the second case, no return code is received, and the function doesn't work.

I tried totally hardcoding the values given.
I implemented that the commands are always formated the same way, and always converted with `float()` (before the `print("Serial command...` line.
So I expected the same behavior for the two codes, and I don't see what changes between the two (since the `print("Serial command ...` line gives the same and is the last line before the command is sent over serial

Thanks !

Comment: Are you sure the random generated values are complying with the allowed input for the send_command() function?
I am just guessing but maybe its a floating-point issue (to many?) or the random multiplication results in to big/ to small numbers?
Whats your "pi" value?
Are you using a built-in constant or e defined number/ string which is assigend to "pi"?

Comment: "_does not work_" is never a good problem description. What do you mean with it? What are the expected and observed behavior? NB: If the output of the `print` statement is the same, the problem is in the code you are not showing here.

Comment: Arduino `Serial` object does read `utf-8`, so your `bytes(command_string, "utf-8")` is wrong. BTW, if all you are sending is a byte array of a string representation of whatever data, then what's the point to convert it a string input to float, pass it in to `send_command()`, and then convert it back to string, then byte array? you could just straightly pass in the string without converting to float.

Comment: @hcheung, why is using UTF-8 wrong? The `Serial.write()` and `Serial.read()` functions **do** work with bytes, so encoding a string using UTF-8 usually is the correct and recommended approach. The conversions to `float` and then `str` also do have the benefit of 1) checking that the inputs are really floating-point numbers, and 2) having control over the format in which the numbers are written. It would be nice if a bytes object could be created in one operation, but Python does not have a bytes variant of f-strings (`b'%.4f%s' % (commands[-1], COMMAND_SEPARATOR)` could have worked though).

Comment: When you dealing PC to PC communication, yes. No it is not a recommended approach when you dealing embedded system like Arduino. You should use encoding of `ASCII` instead of `UTF-8`. If you code for some reason has a character that is not an ASCII, encoding in `UTF-8` would turn it into multiple bytes that an Arduino could interpreted wrongly.

Comment: @hcheung, ASCII is fine as well, if the text is guaranteed to contain only ASCII characters, which it problaby is in this case. But the conversions are still necessary. Passing a `str` object would implicitly encode it (probably with UTF-8, but I'm not sure) because `str` objects **cannot** be directly transmitted over any communication interface.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my code to do ASCII encoding, still doesn't work : is working when putting floats by hand (using `input()`) but not working when giving a float array to `send_command()` inside the code itself (neither with random generated nor hardcoded values)
I want to keep the `float()` conversion because in the end, the goal is to control the stepper by sending float commands only generated in the code, not user inputed so those will be of type `float`. Inputing the values by hand was just a test which, surprinsigly, worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Found the problem :

After every new serial connection, the Arduino resets.
When it resets, it need a little time to start the `loop()` function !

So when I was entering my commands manually, I gave it a little time without noticing, but when the commands were generated inside my Python code, the first command was sent so quickly that it wasn't interpreted by the Arduino, and the function didn't get a return code from the Arduino !

### 2 ways to solve the problem:

**1. Adding a timeout**

```py
TIMEOUT = 2
TIMEOUT_ACTIVE = True

def send_command(commands):

    ### same code as above ### 

    port.write(command_string)
    # wait for arduino's return_code on serial WITH TIMEOUT
    init_time = time()
    while (not TIMEOUT_ACTIVE) or (time() - init_time) <= TIMEOUT:
        if port.inWaiting() > 0:
            return_code = int(port.readline())
            return return_code
```

**2. Waiting before sending the first command**

waiting 2 seconds (tested 1 seconds, was not enough) before begining to send commands

```py
sleep(2)
while True:
    commands = [float(random.random()*pi), float(random.random()*pi)]
    return_code = send_command(commands)
    print(f"return code: {return_code}")
    # don't need the sleep(0.1) anymore
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add logging to receiving part.

Replace this:

```
while True:
    if port.inWaiting() > 0:
        return_code = int(port.readline())
        return return_code
```

With this:

```
import time
while True:
    if port.inWaiting() > 0:
        print(f"Received {port.inWaiting()} bytes.")
        return_code = int(port.readline())
        return return_code
    print("Nothing received yet.")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Maybe your Arduino does not response for request, and you just waiting for the response in infinite loop.

You can also add timeout for response, so after some time if there was no response method *send_command(commands)* will just return None.

Comment: Thanks, added your suggestion. As expected, it the first case (user input with `input()`) it works fine (only two `"Nothing received yet"` lines -> approx. 0.2 seconds before a return code, and `send_command()` returns); but in the second case, with values generated inside the code itself, the `"Nothing received yet."` line keeps printing forever .   
Still don't understand why

Comment: Ok, it means that Arduino does not send a response for a command. Maybe the command format is wrong. Check the output of print(f"Sending command: " + str(command_string))  for working and not working versions. There should be some differences.

Comment: Well there is absolutely no difference I can see. Could there be a difference that is invisible in the terminal (like encoding or something) ? I guess not because that print statement is execut just before writing to the COM port, so the encoding and other conversions are done before that

Comment: @StijnB I think I know what can cause this problem. Try to add time.sleep(1) before return_code = send_command(commands) . Maybe Arduino does not have enough time to initialize.

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you! You weren't very far away from the answer: after implemeting a timeout I realised it's the first command that causes the problem, so adding a sleep(1) before the whole driving loop solved the problem